# Connecting Raspberry Pi to Ubuntu 18.04 through physical Ethernet using SSH

Tags: 18.04, ssh, ethernet, raspberrypi

I am trying to connect my computer to a Raspberry Pi using SSH and a physical ethernet connection with a Netgear Prosafe GS108. My computer has Ubuntu 18.04 installed. My Raspberry the latest version of Raspbian. My Problem is: I can't connect both through the command `$ssh 169.254.200.151`, where `169.254.200.151` is a fixed ip adress I have defined in my Pi. I have however been able to connect several Pis together using the same setup.
I have then tried to ping the fixed IP Adress of My raspberry. I have tried the following options

```
ping 169.254.200.151
ping pi@169.254.200.151
ping user@169.254.200.151
```

And I always get:

```
From 192.168.122.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 169.254.200.151 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 4083ms
pipe 4
```

I think this error is strongly related to the fact that I always see on the top of the screen: `Activation of network failed`, even though I find this warning strange as I am not trying to connect to internet, but just to my Netgear box on which the Raspberry Pi is connected.

I have read a lot of posts but wasn't able to figure out the problem. I am also not really used to this topic so any hint or help would be extremely appreciated.

**Additional information:**

The command `sudo lshw -C network` gives the following:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I211 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 03
       serial: b4:2e:99:31:55:a0
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.4.0-k duplex=full firmware=0. 6-1 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:37 memory:d9500000-d951ffff ioport:2000(size=32) memory:d9520000-d9523fff
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: docker0
       serial: 02:42:d9:82:4e:9c
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
  *-network:1 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: virbr0-nic
       serial: 52:54:00:87:36:c8
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
  *-network:2
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: virbr0
       serial: 52:54:00:87:36:c8
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=192.168.122.1 link=no multicast=yes
```

In my pi I have defined the adress in the following way `$sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf`

```
interface eth0
request address_eth0 169.254.200.151
interface wlan0
request address_wlan0 192.168.43.141
```

I can't tell if the wired connection is correctly configured: [image][image]

Comment: I do not understand using the [168.2540.0/16](https://packetlife.net/blog/2008/sep/24/169-254-0-0-addresses-explained/) network. suggest putting the pi on the same 192.168.122.0/24 (guessing) network as your server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PC and PIs can't talk because they are not on the same IP Subnet.  The simplest thing to do is to manually configure your PC just like the Pis, with an address from the 169.254.XXX.XXX space with a net mask of 255.255.0.0.

It is also possible to add that address to the Ethernet as a secondary address, so that you both have DHCP as well as the manual IP from 169.254...  If you do this, then it will be able to reach the Internet and also the Pis on the same interface.

Comment: That's the answer indeed. Thanks a lot.